# Issue with ModalPopup in asp.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have used modalpopup control in my web application and after open it when i click on ok button i have make call to WCF function to deal with some functional requirement.

Currently the behavior like , when i will click on OK button ModalPopup remained open until my WCF operation is completed and when it will completed it will be closed because i write down logic to hide in code behind file and my code as per below

```
  <asp:Panel ID="PanelCheck" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" SkinID="Custom">
        *Panel content here..*
        <asp:Button ID="OkButton" runat="server" Text="Create" OnClientClick="return  
         ValidateSeconds();" OnClick="OkButton_Click" /> 

  </asp:Panel>

<cc1:modalpopupextender id="MPE" runat="server" targetcontrolid="lnkTemp"  
 popupcontrolid="PanelCheck" backgroundcssclass="modalBackground" />
```

**code behind**

```
    protected void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                MPE.Hide();

                     *Logic to deal with WCF call..* 

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            timerInstance.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

**Now what i require is i need to close modalpopup first and then asynchronously it should make WCF call** I could not find any ways to do that, please anyone help me if this question make any sense.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can hide ModalPopupExtender on the client side right after clicking the “Create” button:

```
<asp:Button ... OnClientClick="return ValidateSeconds();" /> 

function ValidateSeconds() {
    //your code
    $find('MPE').hide();
    //your code
}
```

**See Also:**

[How to Show / Hide a ModalPopupExtender using Javascript](http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2009/05/06/how-to-show-hide-a-modalpopupextender-using-javascript.aspx)

Comment: I can hide the modalpopup using javascript, however my problem is to make wcf call asynchronously so other UI can work as it is

Comment: Perform the ajax callback and call WCF service asynchronously via the jQuery.ajax, for example (do not make postback anymore / do not handle button’s click).

Comment: Hey Mikhail i have make call WCF asynchronously but any other User Interface action will wait until end of this operation can you be more specify your idea with me.